# LayoutProcessor form field validation not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2. I am using the Order Delivery Date extension. Now I want to make the date field require.

It is using a LayoutProcessorPlugin and code as:

```
$dateField = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
                    'id' => 'custom-date',
                    'class' => 'test'

                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_date',
                'label' => 'Custom Date',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 200,

            ];
```

I have tried

```
'validation' => true,
```

and

```
'validation' => ['required-entry' => true,],
```

but both not working.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you create field according to [this example](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-checkoutadditionalfield/blob/master/SR/CheckoutAdditionalField/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php)

That means

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['delivery_date'] = [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'config' => [
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
        'options' => [],
        'id' => 'delivery-date'
    ],
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_date',
    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'visible' => true,
    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
    'sortOrder' => 250,
    'id' => 'delivery-date'
];
```

Following code for validation should work.

```
'validation' => ['required-entry' => true]
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel, but I have already tried it as mentioned in my question and it is not working.

Comment: Which version you have tried? It's working fine 2.1.1

Comment: it is 2.1.1 version

Comment: Then definitely something wrong with your code. Check again. It should work.

Comment: How to set Min date using this example ?

Comment: Got solution from jquery ui. i have used 'minDate' => 1 :)

Comment: can we change validation message as well? i want to change "this is required field" error message to something else?